# Flutter: Firebase Real-Time database orderByChild has no impact on query result

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I have inserted data like this into Firebase Real-Time Database like this way:

[image]

And I query the database back like this way:

```
final databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();
databaseReference
    .child('orders')
    .orderByChild('date_slug')
    .limitToFirst(pageSize)
    .once()
    .then((snapshot) {
  firstPageItems = snapshot.value;

  if (firstPageItems != null) {
    List<dynamic> curretList = [];
    firstPageItems.forEach((orderId, orderData) {

      print ("date_slug " + orderData['date_slug'] + "\r\n\r\n\r\n");
      curretList.add(orderData);
    });

    _list.addAll(curretList);
    _listController.sink.add(_list);
  }
});
```

However, the data didn't come back as sorted as I expected. See the output below.

```
I/flutter (17125): date_slug 2020-04-20 15:52:13
I/flutter (17125): 
I/flutter (17125): 
I/flutter (17125): date_slug 2020-04-20 15:52:11
I/flutter (17125): 
I/flutter (17125): 
I/flutter (17125): date_slug 2020-04-20 15:52:10
I/flutter (17125): 
I/flutter (17125): 
I/flutter (17125): date_slug 2020-04-20 15:52:12
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As soon as you call `firstPageItems = snapshot.value`, you are converting the results into a map/dictionary. A dictionary can hold the keys and the values of the results, but it has no place for the relative order of the results.

To maintain the order of the results, you'll want to either observe `onChildAdded`:

```
var query = databaseReference
    .child('orders')
    .orderByChild('date_slug')
    .limitToFirst(pageSize);
query.onChildAdded
    .forEach((event) => {
      print(event.snapshot.value)
    });
```

If you need to know when all child nodes of your query have been handled, you can add an additional listener to the value event:

```
query.once().then((snapshot) {
  print("Done loading all data for query");
});
```

Adding this additional listener does not result in downloading extra data, as Firebase deduplicates then behind the scenes.

---

Alternatively, you can the [`FirebaseList` class](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_database/latest/ui_firebase_list/FirebaseList-class.html) from the FlutterFire library, which uses that same `onChildAdded` and the other `onChild...` streams to maintain an indexed list.

An example of using this class:

```
list = FirebaseList(query: query, 
  onChildAdded: (pos, snapshot) {},
  onChildRemoved: (pos, snapshot) {},
  onChildChanged: (pos, snapshot) {},
  onChildMoved: (oldpos, newpos, snapshot) {},
  onValue: (snapshot) {
    for (var i=0; i < this.list.length; i++) {
      print('$i: ${list[i].value}');
    }
  }
);
```

As you can see this uses the `onValue` stream of the list to loop over the children in order. The `onChild...` methods are needed for the `FirebaseList` class, but we don't do anything meaningful with them here.

---

In recent versions of the FlutterFire library, the `DataSnapshot` class now has a `children` property, meaning you can *finally* do:

```
query.onValue((event) {
  event.snapshot.children.forEach((child) {
    print(child.value);
  });
})
```

Comment: This works, but how do I know how many item returned by this query?

Comment: You can't determine the total number of results in an `onChildAdded`. You can either keep incrementing a counter in `onChildAdded`, or listen for the entire value.