# How do I print a list from a Firebase Database query using Flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to print a list of attributes from my firebase database. The database is currently structured like this:

[image]

I would first like to print a list of show names to the console so I can see that it works and then add it to a ListView later. Any help is appreciated!

```
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

// This is the model class
class Mod {
  final String name;
  final String nextEpisode;
  final String prevEpisode;

  Mod(this.name, this.nextEpisode, this.prevEpisode);

  Mod.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
    : name = json['name'],
      nextEpisode = json['nextEpisode'],
      prevEpisode = json['prevEpisode'];
}


// This is the screen class
class FTest2 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FTest2State createState() => _FTest2State();
}

class _FTest2State extends State<FTest2> {

  List<Mod> list = List();

  MakeCall() {
    final mainReference = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();
    mainReference.child('-M5Uol7Xldnc8wvNXnNg').once().then((DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
      this.setState(() {
        for(var value in dataSnapshot.value){
          list.add(Mod.fromJson(value));
        }
      });
    });
    print(list);
  }

  void getData() {
    MakeCall();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('This is App Bar for the FB Test')),
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text('Press for data'),
              onPressed: () {
                getData();
              },
            ),
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: What's the problem with the code you shared?

Comment: First, I'm missing the reference to 'show' in the db. After I fix that I'm returning an empty list. Ideally I'd like to return a list of all of the different show names. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looping over the nodes of one specific show, which means that your `value` is actually one of the child properties under that: `name`, `nextEpisode`, `prevEpisode`. What you're probably looking for is to listen to `onChildAdded` for all shows, and then get the `name` property for each:

```
mainReference.child('shows')
  .onChildAdded
  .forEach((event) => {
    print(event.snapshot.key+": "+event.snapshot.value.toString());
    this.setState(() {
      list.add(Mod.fromJson(event.snapshot.value["name"]));
    });
  });
```

Also see my answer form a few weeks ago here: [Flutter: Firebase Real-Time database orderByChild has no impact on query result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61333194/flutter-firebase-real-time-database-orderbychild-has-no-impact-on-query-result/61333575#61333575)

Answer (score 1):

Your reference is wrong, you need to traverse the database from top to the node you want to retrieve, therefore use the following:

```
final mainReference = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference("shows");
mainReference.child('-M5Uol7Xldnc8wvNXnNg').once().then((DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
```

pass the argument `shows` to the `reference()` method.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. This returns an error:
```
final mainReference = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference("shows");
```
This returns an empty list:
```
    final mainReference = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('shows');
    mainReference.once().then((DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
```
This returns '_InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable<dynamic>'

```
    final mainReference = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('shows');
    mainReference.child('-M5Uol7Xldnc8wvNXnNg').once().then((DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
```

Comment: @Stridermn Please use single backticks to mark code in comments.

Comment: I went to sleep and now woke up, anyway check @FrankvanPuffelen answer