# To implement stream subscriptions instead basic queries to get Realtime in Firebase - Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database

Inside the Android App, I have a page (ListaAlimentarPage) that displays a list of records. I am doing tests with several cell phones that write records and I can see that not all cell phones obtain the complete list of records that have been written, so I have to be calling the page constantly until I get the updated list, which makes an experience not user friendly

Somebody advice me that I should change the way I am reading the data (.once) to listening with Streams Subscriptions where the data will be constantly read, however **I don't know how to implement it within my bloc and provider pattern**. Is there a way to do that?

My BLOC pattern looks like this:

```
class AlimentarBloc {

  final _alimentarController = new BehaviorSubject<List<AlimentarModel>>();
  final _cargandoController = new BehaviorSubject<bool>();

  final _alimentarProvider = new AlimentarProvider();

  Stream <List<AlimentarModel>>        get alimentarStream    => _alimentarController.stream;
  Stream <bool>                        get cargando           => _cargandoController.stream;

  Future<List<AlimentarModel>> cargarAlimentar(String idEmpresa, String idEstanque) async {
    final alimentar = await _alimentarProvider.cargarAlimentar(idEmpresa, idEstanque);
    _alimentarController.sink.add(alimentar);
    return alimentar;
  }

  dispose() {
    _alimentarController?.close();
    _cargandoController?.close();
  }
}
```

The query in PROVIDER looks like this...

```
  Future<List<AlimentarModel>> cargarAlimentar(String idEmpresa, String idEstanque) async {

  final List<AlimentarModel> alimentar = new List(); 

  Query resp = db.child('empresas').child(idEmpresa).child('estanques').child(idEstanque).child('loteActual').child('alimentacion');

  final snapshot  = await resp.once();

  if (snapshot.value == null) return [];
  if (snapshot.value['error'] != null) return []; 

  snapshot.value.forEach((id, alim){
    final temp = AlimentarModel.fromJson(Map<String,dynamic>.from(alim));
    temp.idAlimentar = id;

    alimentar.add(temp);
  });
  return alimentar;
}
```

And the list of records are displayed in "ListaAlimentarPage" as following:

```
class ListaAlimentarPage extends StatelessWidget {


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final _prefs = new PreferenciasUsuario();
    
    final alimentarBloc = Provider.alimentarBloc(context);
    alimentarBloc.cargarAlimentar(_prefs.idEmpresa, _prefs.idEstanque);

    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: _crearListado(context, alimentarBloc),
        bottomNavigationBar:  utils.crearBottom(context, 2),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _crearListado(BuildContext context, AlimentarBloc alimentarBloc) {

    return StreamBuilder(
        stream: alimentarBloc.alimentarStream,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<AlimentarModel>> snapshot){
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            final alimentarList = snapshot.data;
            alimentarList.sort((a, b) => b.fecha.compareTo(a.fecha));
            return Container(
              child: Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: alimentarList.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, i) =>_crearItem(context, alimentarBloc, alimentarList[i]),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            );
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text(snapshot.error.toString());
          } 
            return Center (child: Image(image: AssetImage('assets/preloader.gif'), height: 200.0,));
        },
    );
  }

  Widget _crearItem(BuildContext context, AlimentarBloc alimentarBloc, AlimentarModel alimentar) {

      return Stack( 
          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              
              child: Card(
                  child: ListTile(
                    title: Text('${alimentar.nombreAlimentoFull}'),
                    onTap: () => null,
                  ),
              )
            ),
          ],
        );
  }
}
```

My questions are:

1. Is there a simple way to migrate my code to listen the Firebase Data (snapshots) using Stream Subscriptions?
2. Will I obtain the realtime desired experience?
3. Do I need to implement a Refresh Indicator on Scroll Down or something like that?

Comment: so you want to have a rtdb listener?

Comment: Yep. I think so. I need that the users can see the information near realtime instead of calling the page continously and it seems that the .once method that I implemented doesn't work in that way.

Comment: you could use listeners for that. Do you want to me post an example?

Comment: I would like to know where and how implement listeners in my code. Do I need to do changes in my BLOC? In my pattern? In my stream builder?

Comment: You can implement a listener like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61333194/flutter-firebase-real-time-database-orderbychild-has-no-impact-on-query-result