# Fetch users post that matches user ID : Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, flutter-web

guys I'm busy migrating my android app written in Java to flutter but I have a problem.

Below is the code I'm having struggle with converting to flutter. Is there any way I can convert it.

```
posts_ref = db.ref('Posts');
      posts_ref.onValue.listen((e) {
        DataSnapshot datasnapshot = e.snapshot;
        int i = 0;
        if(datasnapshot.numChildren() != null){
          Post post = datasnapshot.val();
          if(post.publisher == user.uid){
            i++;

            posts = i.toString();

          }
        }
      });
```

Below is my Java code in my android application.

```
private void getNrPosts(){
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Posts");
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NotNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                int i = 0;
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    Post post = snapshot.getValue(Post.class);
                    if (post.getPublisher().equals(firebaseUser.getUid())){
                        i++;
                    }
                }
                posts.setText(MessageFormat.format("{0}", i));
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NotNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
  }
```

All help will be very useful and thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the Flutter library for Realtime Database doesn't have a direct equivalent of:

```
for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
```

There's a [feature request](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/711) for it on the repo for the library, but it looks like that was closed.

In the meantime you can listen for the `onChild...` events to accomplish the same. Alternatively, you can use the `FirebaseList` in the library to accomplish the same.

See my longer answer here for an example of both: [Flutter: Firebase Real-Time database orderByChild has no impact on query result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61333194/flutter-firebase-real-time-database-orderbychild-has-no-impact-on-query-result/61333575#61333575)