# Sorting users by a specific value

Tags: android, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I'm making a flutter app and i'm using firebase for database. I have some users and i want to sort them by a spesific value. -for example user's experience points or coin they have like in video games-

I want to make a leaderboard. The user with the most "xp points" will be at the top.

Is the any possible way to do that with my current database schema? Or i have to change my schema and try something else?

I'm recording users with like this path on firebase;

/users/%userid%/user_info/user_values/userXP

/users/%userid%/user_info/user_values/userCoin

all my users in "users" documentation with a unique id.

Comment: What have you tried?  There is plenty of documentation on sorting queries.  I suggest starting with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you should be able to do something like:

```
var ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("users")
var query = ref.orderByChild("user_info/user_values/userXP");
```

And then listen for `child...` or use a `FirebaseList` as shown here: [Flutter: Firebase Real-Time database orderByChild has no impact on query result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61333194/flutter-firebase-real-time-database-orderbychild-has-no-impact-on-query-result/61333575#61333575)