# Do Firebase and Flutter support one-time reads on the web?

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database, flutter-web

I'm using Firebase and Flutter to read a List of Objects (EspecieModel). It's working perfect in IOS and Android, however It doesn't work on the Web (an empty List is retrieved).

I'm reading from Firebase as follows ...

```
Future<List<EspecieModel>> cargarTipoEspecie() async {

  final List<EspecieModel> tipoEspecie = []; 

  Query resp = db.child('PATH/tipoespecie');
  resp.onChildAdded.forEach((element) {
        final temp = EspecieModel.fromJson(Map<String,dynamic>.from(element.snapshot.value));
        temp.idEspecie = element.snapshot.key;
        tipoEspecie.add(temp);   
  });
  await resp.once().then((snapshot) {
    print("Loaded - ${tipoEspecie.length}");
  });
      return tipoEspecie;

}
```

And I'm using a Future Builder to display the information...

```
FutureBuilder(
        future: _tipoEspecieBloc.cargarTipoEspecie(), 
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
            // print(snapshot.connectionState);
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done && snapshot.hasData{
              // print(snapshot.data);
              final _especies = snapshot.data;
                   return Stack(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: _especies!.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, i) { 
                          return _crearItem(context, _especies[i], i);
                        },
                      ),
                    ],
                  );   
            } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
              print(snapshot.error);
              return Text(snapshot.error.toString());
            }
            else {
              return //CircleProgressIndicator Code
            );
            }
        },
      ),
```

I can't identify what I'm doing wrong

**How to do a one-time Firebase Query that works well on IOS, Android, and also on the Web??**

Answer (score 2):

This won't work:

```
resp.onChildAdded.forEach((element) {
     final temp = EspecieModel.fromJson(Map<String,dynamic>.from(element.snapshot.value));
     temp.idEspecie = element.snapshot.key;
     tipoEspecie.add(temp);   
});
await resp.once().then((snapshot) {
 print("Loaded - ${tipoEspecie.length}");
});
return tipoEspecie;
```

The `onChildAdded` is not part of the `await`, so I doubt everything waits the way you seem to want. Just adding `await` in one place, does not make the rest of your code synchronous.

Instead consider using just `once()` and then populating your `tipoEspecie` array by looping over `snapshot.value.values` (a relatively new [addition to the API](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/pull/5765)).

```
var snapshot = await resp.once();
snapshot.value.values.forEach((node) {
  final temp = EspecieModel.fromJson(Map<String,dynamic>.from(node.value));
  temp.idEspecie = node.key;
  tipoEspecie.add(temp);   
});
return tipoEspecie;
```

Note: I'm not completely sure of the `.forEach` and the code in there. So if you get errors there, check what type you get back from `.values` and what `node` is, to get the correct key and values from it.

Comment: Thanks @puf. It gives an error: `NoSuchMethodError: 'values'
method not found
Receiver: null
Arguments: []`.

Comment: One year ago, I implemented a query of this type...   `var snapshot = await resp.once();  snapshot.value.forEach((id, item){
    final temp = EspecieModel.fromJson(Map<String,dynamic>.from(item));
    temp. idEspecie = id;
    tipoEspecie.add(temp);
  });` I just saw that it works well on the web, however I had a lot of problems when using it on IOS and Android in an Online / Offline scenario. That is why I switched to the OnChild method

Comment: Do you know any similar query to onChildAdded that works on the Web (as I'm sure it does on IOS and Android - On / Off Scenario)?

Comment: If you have a recent SDK, the `values` will give you the ordered results in a `once()` listener across all supported platforms. As said, I am not completely certain of the syntax, which is why I linked the PR in hopes you can use that to help you find the exact incantation. --- Alternatively, you can do: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61333194/flutter-firebase-real-time-database-orderbychild-has-no-impact-on-query-result/61333575#61333575. I used `FrebaseList` for most of my code before the `values` were introduced.

Comment: Hi @puf. I want to share with you the results of my tests evaluating each alternative, please correct me where I am wrong. I'll divide it into three sections ...

Comment: 1. I am using the latest SDK version (firebase_database 8.0.1) and I confirm that something like snapshot.value.values ​​does not appear. If it is possible to do the code through snapshot.value, but unless they have modified something, it has quite a few problems in operation as it is not predictable (it does not always bring all the data) as I shared in the last comments.

Comment: 2. So I chose to try the alternative solutions. One of them is the one I'm already using with `resp.onChild`. This solution works very well on IOS and Android **when await is included** in `resp.once`, but it doesn't work correctly on Web (the first time it loads the data and the following times it does not).

Comment: 3. The FirebaseList solution is working for me on IOS, Android and Web, so it seems that it will be the solution to test with a greater number of clients. I implemented it using the field of onChildAdded and not the one of onValue (some errors came out). I had to add an `await resp.once` to it so that it works correctly and loads all the data.

Comment: @puf Your answers and comments are always helpful. I upvoted the comment and the response of the link that you sent me. Thanks.