# Flutter - EmptyState for FirebaseAnimatedList

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using FirebaseAnimatedList for a chat flutter project with Firebase Realtime Chat.

How can I do to use an empty state when the query of FirebaseAnimatedList doesn't have results?

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever anything happens in the state of the `FirebaseAnimatedList` its `_onValue` method will get called at the end of that. So you can override `_onValue` and check if there are any items in the list at that point.

For an example of something similar on the regular `FirebaseList` (which works similarly), have a look at my answer here: [Flutter: Firebase Real-Time database orderByChild has no impact on query result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61333194/flutter-firebase-real-time-database-orderbychild-has-no-impact-on-query-result/61333575#61333575)

Comment: Can I ask you an example with FirebaseAnimatedList?

Comment: No. But if you give it a try yourself based on the link I provided, I'll gladly have a look at your code.